# Azure App Service (Mobile) relogin hangs

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile Apps with deployment slots, with the service provider for login being Microsoft. I have some odd behaviour, during swapping and the users relogin.

Is the performance better/different for AD? [read that it was not for GA yet?]

I am developing in a developer slot with everything specifically configured for this environment, the test and updates are working. I upload the server to staging, now utilizing the same db and settings (except microsoft authentication). The server is again verified to be working both on client and server.

I then use swap to change the staging and production slots. The production slot has the microsoft account login settings.

Upon swap the login by users are continuing indefinitely (no timeout, i.e. several minutes running without any stop) if, the referesh token call is made, as per [this link](https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/):

```
//retrieve user info
user = new MobileServiceUser(credential.UserName);
credential.RetrievePassword();
//refresh token
user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = credential.Password;
JObject refreshJson = (JObject)await ((App)Application.Current).MobileService.InvokeApiAsync(
                        "/.auth/refresh",
                        System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get,
                        null);
```

My initial question is therefore is it possible to insert a timeout e.g. 2 seconds on the call to force the user to re-enter their credentials?

Because it seems to work if the user logs out and then back in with normal login procedure:

```
user = await ((App)Application.Current).MobileService.LoginAsync(provider);
credential = new PasswordCredential(provider.ToString(), user.UserId, user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
vault.Add(credential);
string newToken = refreshJson["authenticationToken"].Value<string>();
```

## Question(s)

Is it possible to insert timeout on `MobileServiceClient.invokeApiAsync` calls?

Is there some setting that can be set so the swap mechanism does not introduce this issue?

Is there a way to improve the login/relogin flow, the users are complaining that the login is failing often. I cannot replicate it in other instances than during the swap. Can this be because of distance to the server?
Therefore would `Traffic Manager` be a solution? However, I cannot see how it should be enabled if I am using microsoft login. Since a service is bound to an application name for authentication. How should the `Traffic Manager` be used in this respect?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some setting that can be set so the swap mechanism does not introduce this issue?

Not sure if this applies to your case, but there is a known issue where certain app settings can actually *cause* issues with swapping. Do you have any app settings defined that end with **_EXTENSION_VERSION**  or that start with **WEBSITE_AUTH_**? If so, try removing them and see if that resolves the issues you're seeing.

> Is there a way to improve the login/relogin flow, the users are complaining that the login is failing often. I cannot replicate it in other instances than during the swap. Can this be because of distance to the server?

I've never head of an issue like this. Anymore details on the failure you can provide, such as a status code? One thing you can do is enable [Application Logging](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/) and you should be able to get detailed information about the refresh failures.

> Therefore would Traffic Manager be a solution? However, I cannot see how it should be enabled if I am using microsoft login. Since a service is bound to an application name for authentication. How should the Traffic Manager be used in this respect?

I think the way to make this work is to use a single Microsoft account application for all mobile app backends that are being load-balanced by traffic manager. The redirect URL that gets configured needs to use the common host name that is registered with Traffic Manager.

Comment: Hello thx for your answer. I have application logging, and the only impact I am seeing is extreme load of pages. Since the call never times out :-\ regarding traffic manager, okay so the client initialization is towards the traffic manager url? But as far as I can see it has no settings for authentication ? Regarding the issue not when I look in the portal, is there a reference explorer for the service in general, i.e. Under the hood? Because I cannot find this parameter. Where should it be?

Comment: Hello again could you clarify the questions in the comment above?

Comment: Correct, traffic manager has no auth settings. Auth settings are only for your App Service app. I don't know what could be causing long latency. Is your application under heavy CPU or memory pressure?

Comment: Finally had time to return to this subject. No it is just during the login that the latency is happening. Could you tell me where I could find the appsettings you refer? Regarding the Traffic manager, I understand what you say, but not how to execute on it. Is there any tutorial or help regarding using the traffic manager together with the authentication?

Comment: Hello again could you clarify the questions in the comment above? :)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of any such tutorial at this time.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to insert timeout on MobileServiceClient.invokeApiAsync calls?

From the API, It seems we can not set timeout in this method, refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt691682%28v=azure.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for more details.